# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Software Recommendations's [second moderator election](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: RockPaperLizard]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Please join me in thanking Undo, who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5744175140044800/0).

Answer (score 11):

Thank you to the community for voting me as your new moderator.

Many thanks to Undo for his great job as moderator and for helping to keep our community strong.

A special thank you to Journeyman Geek for volunteering to serve and for participating in the election.

I look forward to working with the other moderators to keep our community healthy and strong, and to keep our content relevant and valuable.

Comment: Thank you, and congratulations. You'll do a great job, have fun at it!

Comment: Congratulations! The results were rather close, as both you and JG clearly have the capability to do a great job in this role. Looking forward to collaborating with you :-)

Comment: @Undo  You're welcome, and thank *you*.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Thank you!  I look forward to collaborating with you as well.

Comment: Congrats! @RockPaperLizard.

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar Thank you Abhishek!

Comment: Congratulations! happy to see new enthusiasm voted and elected. Good luck!